# Formatar double com milhar e decimal

Tags: c#, .net, string

Tenho o seguinte valor:

```
43239.110000000001
```

Usei este comando:

```
txtSomatorio.Text = String.Format( "{0:#.#,##}", somatorio);
```

Consegui isto:

```
43239,11
```

Como fazer para exibir assim?

```
43.239,11
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Formatar valor com máscara de moeda brasileira](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48012/formatar-valor-com-m%c3%a1scara-de-moeda-brasileira)

Comment: @MatheusMiranda essa é mais antiga do que a que você votou, a outra deveria ser a dup.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Tente usar desta forma:

```
string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", somatorio); // saída = 43.239,11
```

Ou assim:

```
string.Format("{0:N}", 43239,11)); // saída = 43.239,11
```

Comment: a opção `"{0:0.0,00}"` não funcionou, mas `"{0:N}"` deu certo. Obrigado.

Comment: @Jota, estranho, aqui funciona as duas.

Comment: Estanho mesmo `string a = String.Format( "{0:0.0,00}", somatorio); ///"43239,110"`, estou usando o VS 2012 e somente a segunda funcionou. Vai entender. kk

Comment: @Jota, kkkk, inverti o ponto e a vírgula. talvez seja por isso.

Comment: Matou a charada `a = String.Format( "{0:0,0.00}", somatorio); //"43.239,11"`, agora sim!

Comment: Boa meu caro!!!!

Answer (score 26):

As duas respostas postadas estão corretas, mas cabe um adendo com relação à cultura utilizada. As respostas mostram como é o normal de ser utilizado se você tem certeza que um computador está configurado com uma cultura que dá o resultado que você espera ou ainda se o que você espera na verdade não é o formato informado mas o formato monetário que o usuário está esperando, ou seja, o formato que estiver no computador dele (o que é uma boa ideia)

Se você quer garantir que o formato seja este que você disse em qualquer computador precisa dizer qual a [cultura a ser usada no código](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Format_System_IFormatProvider_System_String_System_Object___):

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", 43239.11));
```

Precisa usar o *namespace* `System.Globalization`.

É possível inclusive criar uma cultura nova do jeito que melhor te agradar:
using System.Globalization;

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var minhaCultura = new CultureInfo("pt-BR"); 
        minhaCultura.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        minhaCultura.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm";
        minhaCultura.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
        minhaCultura.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "_";
        minhaCultura.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format(minhaCultura, "{0:N}", 43239.11));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2iK3EU). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dn86WY). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Culture/Especific%2Ccs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Valeu o complemento.

Answer (score 11):

Basta usar, o número 2 é a quantidade de casas decimais.

```
txtSomatorio.Text = somatorio.ToString("n2");
```

**Resultado**:
43.239,11

Comment: Funcionou, mas vou usar `"{0:N}"`, pois tenho de formatar dentro do gridview também. Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Jota, eu acho que o comando funciona normalmente pra GridView também.

Comment: Então poso usar no `Eval`!? Vou testar depois. Vivendo e aprendendo, ou não! kkkkk

Comment: Você só precisa converter antes: `decimal.Parse(Eval("somatorio").ToString()).ToString("n2")`