# Formatar valor com máscara de moeda brasileira

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Tenho uma stored procedure que me devolve um valor de crédito para determinada cota de consórcio.

O retorno desse valor seria assim: 
`167900`.

Porém deveria ser assim:
`R$ 167.900,00`.

Esse valor eu alimento uma `<td>` em um `repeater`, o qual eu pego dessa forma:

`<td><asp:Label ID="lblCreditoCota" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreditoDisponivel") %>' /></td>`

Gostaria de mascara esse valor pela máscara do Real(Brasil). Como faço isso?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Você pode usar o **string.Format**, passando o formato **C** (*currency*):

```
<td>
    <asp:Label 
        ID="lblCreditoCota" 
        runat="server" 
        Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("CreditoDisponivel")) %>' />
</td>
```

É claro que este código simplesmente utiliza a cultura padrão para exibição da moeda.

Eventualmente é necessário se preocupar com a variação da cultura ou é necessário exibir o valor monetário em outra moeda que não a da cultura local. Neste caso você precisa forçar a cultura.

Uma maneira de forçar a cultura usando o **string.Format** é:

```
var valorFormatado = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:C}", valor)
```

Existe ainda um cenário onde é necessário mostrar um valor monetário em moeda estrangeira, mas como se está mostrando para brasileiros, deseja-se usar a cultura de separadores de milhar e decimal dos brasileiros.

Neste caso você pode-se fixar a moeda desejada, formatar o número com os separadores de milhar e decimal, e informar a cultura da qual se deseja obter estes separadores:

```
var valorFormatado = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "US$ {0:#,###.##}", valor)
```

Por fim, [uma solução bem bacana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10428736/1274092) que mostra a moeda estrangeira usando os separadores da cultura local, independentemente de qual seja esta cultura local:

```
// obtém a cultura local
var cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; 
// faz uma cópia das informações de formatação de número da cultura local
var numberFormatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo)cultureInfo.NumberFormat.Clone();
// fixa o símbolo da moeda estrangeira
numberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol = "US$";
// obtém o valor em moeda estrangeira formatado conforme a cultura local
var valorFormatado = string.Format(numberFormatInfo, "{0:C}", valor);
```