# Como formatar valores com formatos de strings customizados?

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatação, mschart

Estou desenvolvendo um gráfico e gostaria de colocar os valores do eixo Y conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: modelo do gráfico]

Verifiquei que é possível fazer isso através dos [formatos de strings customizados](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) dessa maneira `ChartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "formato customizado"`, porém não consegui criar um formato para saída que preciso, alguém tem ideia de qual formato usar para chegar na saída esperada?

**Itens de pesquisa**: 
[Formatting chart axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025263/formatting-chart-axis-labels)
[Formatar valor com máscara de moeda brasileira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48012/18327)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta foi mudada e vou tentar salvar a resposta na medida do que eu posso.

Use isto:

```
private void chart1_FormatNumber(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.FormatNumberEventArgs e) {
    if(e.ElementType == System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType.AxisLabels) {
        switch(e.Format) {
            case "formato customizado":
                e.LocalizedValue = string.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"), "{0:F1}", e.Value / 1000);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja o resultado só da [formatação no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ncHibL). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kyv1Zu). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/FormatCulture.cs).

Me baseei nessa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401627/221800).

Comment: No caso, a tabela na pergunta é só para demostrar a entrada no eixo Y e qual a saída que espero, porém o gráfico é preenchido automaticamente e os intervalos dos eixos também são gerados automaticamente

Comment: Ok, e o que isto significa? Você quer formatar só o número?

Comment: Sim, por exemplo `ChartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:0,}";`

Comment: `ChartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format` não é um `String.Format`. Isto é outra coisa de alguma biblioteca que você está usando. Você tem que explicar melhor sua pergunta. Qual é o tipo dos números?

Comment: Ajustei a pergunta, se achar que descaracteriza a primeira, me fala que excluo essa e crio uma nova