# Formatar saída tipo double com ponto ao invés de virgula

Tags: c#, asp.net, number-format

Eu tenho uma coleção de coordendas para popular o repeater, com nome da cidade, latitude e longitude.

```
 .aspx

 <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="repetidor">
        var markers = [
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server" Visible="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  cidade: <%# Eval("NomeCidade")%>,
                     lat: <%# String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:D}", Eval("Latitute")) %>,
                     lng: <%# String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:D}", Eval("Longitude")) %>,
                </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                    -
            </SeparatorTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
        ]
    </div>
```

eu pego assim as coordenadas;

```
     .aspx.cs            

       (...)
                var address = coordenadas.NomeCidade + ", Brasil";
                var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
                var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(address);
                coordenadas.Latitude = point.Latitude;
                coordenadas.Longitude = point.Longitude;
                coordenadasColecao.Add(coordenadas);

        (...)
            rptMarkers.DataSource = coordenadasColecao;
            rptMarkers.DataBind();
        (...)
```

Eu gostaria que saísse assim: 46.1475292 ao invés de 46,1475292

Comment: Latitude é uma variável? Por que está usando Eval? Poderia dar um exemplo que possamos reproduzir?

Comment: sim, uma variavel. Eu populo um repeater com uma coleção de coordenadas.

Comment: E o exemplo, **cadê**? Eu fiz 3 perguntas, você só respondeu a 1 e 2, posta um exemplo mais claro do código de maneira que possamos reproduzir para entender a sua necessidade e podermos dar sugestões que realmente funcionem de como resolver.

Comment: sim, postei o código q estou usando.

Comment: Qual o valor que está passando nesta parte `Eval("Latitute")`?

Comment: a latitude com a virgula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça a conversão para [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) depois use o comando [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx) da [classe String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<%#Eval("Latitude").ToString().Replace(",",".")%>
```

***Referencias:***

- [Classe String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método String.Replace (Char, Char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Não sei como está recebendo esse valor, pois geralmente ele já vem com **ponto**, como pode ser visto [no GitHub oficial](https://github.com/sethwebster/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/blob/master/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/MapPoint.cs) da API que está utilizando.

Porém, você pode fazer um simples `Replace()`, caso deseje.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:D}", "46,1475292").Replace(",","."));
```

Você também tem as [cadeias de caracteres](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) para formatar da forma que deseja.

No demais, você pode olhar a pergunta de [Como formatar Double](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44957/20615) que acho que terá mais algumas ideias de como fazer o que deseja.

Comment: não consegui com replace.

Comment: @Daniel Deu algum erro?

Comment: Format specifier was invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `String.Format` e force também com o `Globalization`

```
<%# string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              "{0:D}", Eval("Latitude")) %>
```

Comment: Exception Details: System.FormatException: Format specifier was invalid.

Comment: creio que ele não estava vindo como decilmal então

Comment: o controle exibe com virgula, mas na variável consta o ponto. Foi resolvido com a solução proposta pelo @Virgilio Novic

Comment: Fiz a resposta antes da edição da pergunta, como é uma string e vai continuar string um simples replace funciona, se precisar decimal ai utilize minha resposta.