# Cifrão junto ao número na formatação ToString

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, formatação

Quando tento formatar um valor utilizando `.ToString("c2")` do .NET o simbolo da moeda vem grudado com o número. Isso torna a formatação feia e errada ao meu ponto de vista.

Exemplo:

```
cdec("1234.56").toString("c2") | Resultando: "R$1.234,56"
```

Gostaria que retornasse: "R$ 1.234,56" (Cifrão separado do número).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa para você seria pegar o simbolo de moeda e concatenar com o valor usando a formatação de decimal `N2`.

Ficaria assim:

```
Decimal value = 1106.20m;
Console.WriteLine($"Current Culture: {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}");
Console.WriteLine($"Currency Symbol: {NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol}");
Console.WriteLine($"Currency Value:  {NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol} {value:N2}");
```

Comment: Obrigado Pablo, acabei fazendo uma extension do Decimal para isso usando essa sua opção. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode não gostar, mas o nosso símbolo é assim. Se deseja usar outro pode formatar como um número normal ([`F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou [`N`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) e adicional do símbolo monetário manualmente.

Pode [mudar o símbolo na nossa cultura](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou [criar uma cultura diferente do jeito que precisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44962/101).

Comment: Se a pessoa que negativou disser o que está errado na minha resposta eu posso melhorá-la.

Comment: Não fui eu quem o negativou, mas agradeço sua resposta. Infelizmente não achei algo oficial sobre o espaçamento do símbolo da moeda. Contudo, no windows 7 utilizava sem problemas a função, já no windows 10 aconteceu isso de juntar. Enfim... Agradeço a resposta.

Comment: @EleisonChristiano na verdade não tem problema algum, a pessoa que negativou negativou mais coisas, ela deve estar com raiva de mim. Eu perguntei pra ver se era um caso que a pessoa se enganou. Note que o primeiro parágrafo é igual a outra resposta e o segundo mostra algo que a pessoa pode, e deveria fazer. Ainda que eu não goste é menos gambiarra que a primeira solução que não formata valor monetário. Se um dia muda o símbolo você vai ter que caça na aplicação todo lugar que deve mudar. E eu sei que você não negativou. É o que eu falei, não tem espaço porque foi definido assim no Windows.

Comment: Sim, basicamente sua resposta é igual a anterior. Eu já havia cogitado esta opção (que acabei adotando) mas é lamentável não ter a formatação direta via toString. Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: @EleisonChristiano Qual opção você adotou?

Comment: Acabei fazendo uma extension da string com a formatação proposta pelas duas opções apresentada. Pois na verdade a sua e a resposta anterior são semelhantes, mudando apenas a Sintax.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o `{0:C}`

```
double valor;
valor = double.Parse(txtValor.Text);

MessageBox.Show("O valor é " +String.Formart("{0:C}", valor));
```

Ele pega o valor do `TextBox` e exibe no `MessageBox` no valor na moeda corente real

ficando assim valor inserido 1000 = R$1.000,00

Segue abaixo meu script para calcular reajuste de salário ele não está completo mas talvez ajude-o a enter

```
        double salario, percentual, aumento, novosal,a5,a10,a15,a20;
        salario = double.Parse(txtSalario.Text);
        a5  = salario * 5 / 100;
        a10 = salario * 10 / 100;
        a15 = salario * 15 / 100;
        a20 = salario * 20 / 100;

        if(salario <= 280)
        {
            novosal = salario + a20;
            percentual = 10*20/100;
            aumento = a20;

            MessageBox.Show("O salário é " +String.Format("{0:C}",salario)+ "\n o percentual de aumento é "+percentual+"\n o valor do aumento foi de" +String.Format("{0:C}",aumento));
        }
        else if (salario > 280 && salario < 700)
        {
            novosal = salario + a15;
            percentual = salario * 15 / 100;
            aumento = a15;

            MessageBox.Show("O salário é " +String.Format("{0:C}",salario) + "\n o percentual de aumento é " + percentual + "\n o valor do aumento foi de" +String.Format("{0:C}", aumento));
        }
        else if (salario > 700 && salario <1500)
        {
            novosal = salario + a10;
            percentual = salario * 10 / 100;
            aumento = a10;

            MessageBox.Show("O salário atual é " +String.Format("{0:C}", salario) + "\n O percentual de aumento foi de " +percentual+ "\n O aumento foi de " + String.Format("{0:C}",aumento) +"\n Salário atualizado é de "+String.Format("{0:C}", novosal));
        }
        else if (salario >= 1500)
        {
            novosal = salario + a5;
            percentual = salario * 5 / 100;
            aumento = a5;

            MessageBox.Show("O salário é " +String.Format("{0:C}", salario) + "\n o percentual de aumento é " + percentual + "\n o valor do aumento foi de" +String.Format("{0:C}", aumento));
        }
```

espero ter ajudado

Comment: Sugiro corrigir as gralhas tal como `String.Formart` e focar a resposta no que interessa, sem incluir TextBoxes e MessageBoxes.